# Is a bank account or branch manager able to give higher interest rates on CDs to preferred clients?

Tags: investing, banking, bank-account, interest-rate, certificate-of-deposit

Can an account manager or branch manager of your bank give you higher interest rates on savings or CDs (Certificates of Deposit) if you are a preferred client?  For instance, if a long time client who held funds at the bank for a long time was thinking of moving their funds to a different institution would the manager have the authority to match the other bank's rates?

Comment: By the way, I am not asking about things like 'relationship banking', but a specific case such as the manager having to make a decision on the fly with the client not interested in choosing a product such as 'preferred status'.

Comment: This would be institution specific, and likely wouldn't happen if it could unless that amount on deposit was significant to the bank.

Comment: Thanks @A.K. if you know this to be true from personal experience esp. work experience I would be happy to say that you have answered my question.

Comment: In the US, the SIPC coverage limit is $250k.  Many businesses, including financial institutions, provide the title of preferred customer, client, etc.  For the most part, it's usually a meaningless label. If you're dealing with an investment bank and seven figures then you might find some "preferred" treatment  but no account or branch manager of a  major bank is going to give you a higher interest rate on savings or CD for "only" $250k.  Bank policy (rates) is set by upper level management not branch managers.

Comment: I think you've answered my question @BobBaerker